# Use ImageMagick to Generate Image from Text?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, imagemagick, ubuntu-16.04, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to use ImageMagick to create thumbnail images that are 3840 x 2160.

I need the image to have a black background and white text.  The text should be centered vertically and horizontally.

I want to be able to set a font size, but if the text would extend off the image, automatically decrease the font size so it fits with some amount of padding on the left and right.

I will be doing this in bulk with several hundred thousand images.  From what I've been able to find, it looks like you always have to set a font size and there's no way to make it dynamic.

Can anyone confirm if this is possible to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set a size that specifies how large a space is available for your text and **ImageMagick** will choose the largest pointsize text that will fit:

```
magick -gravity center -background black -fill white -size 400x300 -font /System/Library/Fonts/MarkerFelt.ttc    caption:"Short Text" short.png
```

[image]

```
magick -gravity center -background black -fill white -size 400x300 -font /System/Library/Fonts/MarkerFelt.ttc    caption:"Somewhat longer text that will get rendered in a smaller font" long.png
```

[image]

---

If you want a margin around the text, you can set a maximum size for the text, then increase the size of the canvas with `-extent` - I'll do that in red so you can see what the `-extent` added:

```
magick -gravity center -background black -fill white -size 400x300 -font /System/Library/Fonts/MarkerFelt.ttc    caption:"Somewhat longer text" -background red -extent 410x400 long.png
```

[image]

---

If you are reading lines from files to generate your hundreds of thousands of images, you can pipe the text in from another command like this:

```
echo -n "Text supplied by other command" | magick -gravity center -background black -fill white -size 400x300 -font /System/Library/Fonts/MarkerFelt.ttc caption:@- result.png
```

[image]

---

If you want to know what pointsize **ImageMagick** chose, you can get it like this:

```
magick identify -format "%[caption:pointsize]\n" result.png
59
```

Comment: If you are on macOS or Linux, you can do several 100,000 images very fast with **GNU Parallel**. Ping me if you are interested in that.

Comment: There's no way to specify a pointsize?

Comment: @Geremia You can set a pointsize but this question was specifically about **NOT** setting a pointsize and instead specifying a canvas size that **ImageMagick** should fill with the biggest/best font it can fit.

Comment: I found the "[`-pointsize`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#pointsize)" option.  Thanks. 

Answer (score 1):

I use the following script to generate text based thumbnails, with all my favorite ttf font files, copied to the same folder before:

```
ls -1 *.ttf | while read line
do
magick -gravity center -background '#086cdf' -fill '#f1fffe' -size 490x400 -font "$line" caption:"Sample Text" -background red -extent 500x500 "$(echo "$line"|sed 's/.ttf/_icon.png/')"
done
```

The above script generates icon sized thumbnails with size of 500x500 pixels.

For social media platforms like youtube, thumbnails must be of size 1280x720 for which i use the following script, to generate it:

```
ls -1 *.ttf | while read line
do
magick -gravity center -background '#086cdf' -fill '#f1fffe' -size 1270x620 -font "$line" caption:"Sample Text" -background red -extent 1280x720 "$(echo "$line"|sed 's/.ttf/_Social_Media_Platforms.png/')"
done
```

Hope all these scripts help someone googling for a solution.