# Wrap text and adjust font to container in PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to create a program for making a bingo, and I have everything set up except putting the text, which may range from a single word to even a whole sentence, into each field. How would I go about wrapping that text and adjusting the font size so it fits into each field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of a way of auto-sizing text with PIL, but you can do it with [wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.2/). I am not that experienced with `wand`, but you can use the `caption()` method if you want your text auto-wrapped and sized. I changed the code between runs to write a small amount of text and a considerably longer text in an area I marked in white:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from wand.image import Image
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.font import Font

# Create a red canvas 600x300
with Image(width=600, height=300, pseudo='xc:red') as canvas:
    left, top, width, height = 10, 20, 400, 150
    with Drawing() as context:
        context.fill_color = 'white'
        context.rectangle(left=left, top=top, width=width, height=height)
        font = Font('/System/Library/Fonts/MarkerFelt.ttc')
        context(canvas)
        canvas.caption('Considerably longer text that will need a smaller font and some wrapping too', left=left, top=top, width=width, height=height, font=font, gravity='center')
    canvas.save(filename='result.png')
```

[image]

[image]

There are examples of more sophisticated wrapping techniques using Python's `textwrap` in the wand [documentation](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.2/guide/draw.html#texts).

**Keywords**: wand, image processing, python, caption, auto-wrap, auto-size, word wrap.

Comment: By the way, if for some reason you don't want install `wand`, you could *"shell out"* with `subprocess.run()` and call command-line **ImageMagick** as here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63043486/2836621