# Python PIL - Write text on image in invisible text box with paragraphs

Tags: python, image, text, python-imaging-library

I search a way to write text automatically on images. I actually use PIL to do this (see code below).

It works great, but I search a way to write this text in a fixed "invisible" textbox that insert paragraphs and line breaks automatically - with my code the text is written on the image but it's too long and only one line - so a part of the text is outside of the image.

Any idea how to do this? Is there a function in this PIL-Lib or maybe another lib to do this?

```
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

image = Image.open("bg.png")

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# create font object with the font file and specify
# desired size

font = ImageFont.truetype('AGENCYR.TTF', size=45)

# starting position of the message

(x, y) = (250, 200)
message = "Text text text text text text text text"
color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'  # black color

# draw the message on the background

draw.text((x, y), message, fill=color, font=font)
(x, y) = (250, 650)
name = "username"
color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'  # white color
draw.text((x, y), name, fill=color, font=font)

# return img size

# size() returns a tuple of (width, height)
image_size = image.size
print(image_size)
# create the ImageFont instance

# save the edited image

a = random.randint(1,10000000)
astring = str(a)
savename = "img_" + astring + ".png"

image.save(savename)
```

Comment: The images have a fixed size every time - my idea was to maybe set something like a letter limit for each line, an if letter limit is reached -> write on new line

Comment: This should help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089810/2836621