# How to use MagickImage/Wand to create an image comprised of equally spaced bordered boxes of text in Python

Tags: python, image, imagemagick, wand

I need to make an image that looks like the following:

[image]

To do so, I've implemented the use of MagickImage/Wand. Here is my current implementation

```
import re
from unicodedata import normalize

from docx import Document
from wand.image import Image
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.font import Font

doc = Document("P.docx")
docText = []
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    docText.append(para.text)
fullText = "\n".join(docText)

ct = 242


def get(source, begin, end):
    try:
        start = source.index(len(begin)) + len(begin)
        finish = source.index(len(end), len(start))
        return source[start:finish]
    except ValueError:
        return ""


def capitalize(string):
    cap = ("".join(j[0].upper() + j[1:]) for j in string)
    return cap


def find_matches(text):
    return capitalize(
        [
            m
            for m in re.findall(
                r"^[^0-9]\s+([^.;]+\s*)+[.;]+", normalize("NFKD", text), re.MULTILINE
            )
        ]
    )

with Image(width=300, height=300, psuedo='xc:black') as canvas:
    left, top, width, height = 50, 10, 100, 150
    for match in find_matches(text=fullText):
        ct += 1
        match_words = match.split(" ")
        match = " ".join(match_words[:-1])
        with Drawing() as context:
            context.fill_color = 'white'
            context.rectangle(left=left, top=top, width=width, height=height)
            canvas.font = Font('/System/Library/Fonts/arial.ttf')
            context(canvas)
            canvas.caption(match + '\r' + 'ct', left=left, top=top, width=width, height=height, gravity='center')
        canvas.save(filename='patdrawTest.png')
```

I'm not quite certain on how to create borders or how to properly space things with this tool, and as such, this is my current output:

[image]

I understand I need to have a base image that is iterated over. I also understand that I will need flags in order to keep track of the height/width/etc. of the previous blocks of text (unless there is an easier way of doing so with this tool). However, the way my code currently works is that it takes in words from a word document, parses it to get specific matches, and then is *supposed* to put it into an image like the first image I showed above. Yet, I am at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the related question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67982791/2836621 I left the `height` unset so that ImageMagick would make the caption 300px wide and however tall is necessary. I am unsure how you would do this with **wand** `caption()` method. Maybe @emcconville will know?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I've come up with in order to make equally-spaced boxes of text.

```
import re
from unicodedata import normalize

from docx import Document
from wand.image import Image
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.font import Font

doc = Document("P.docx")
docText = []
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    docText.append(para.text)
fullText = "\n".join(docText)

ct = 242


def get(source, begin, end):
    try:
        start = source.index(len(begin)) + len(begin)
        finish = source.index(len(end), len(start))
        return source[start:finish]
    except ValueError:
        return ""


def capitalize(string):
    cap = ("".join(j[0].upper() + j[1:]) for j in string)
    return cap


def find_matches(text):
    return capitalize(
        [
            m
            for m in re.findall(
                r"^[^0-9]\s+([^.;]+\s*)+[.;]+", normalize("NFKD", text), re.MULTILINE
            )
        ]
    )


with Image(width=400, height=1000, pseudo='xc:white') as canvas:
    left, top, width, height = 2, 2, 395, 131
    for match in find_matches(text=fullText):
        ct += 1
        match_words = match.split(" ")
        match = " ".join(match_words[:-1])
        with Drawing() as context:
            context.fill_color = 'black'
            context.rectangle(left=left, top=top, width=width, height=height)
            context.fill_color = 'white'
            context.rectangle(left=(left+2), top=(top+2), width=(width-4), height=(height-4))
            canvas.font = Font('/System/Library/Fonts/timesnewroman.ttf')
            context(canvas)
            canvas.caption(match + '\n' + str(ct), left=(left+5), top=top, width=(width-10), height=height,
                           gravity='center')
        top += 135
    canvas.crop(bottom=top)
    canvas.save(filename='patdrawTest.png')
```

Here is the output with this code:

[image]

I do, however, still have something I'd like to address. While the boxes of text are all equally-spaced and look rather nice, I'd still prefer that all of the text looks the same; that is the same font-size, and the only way to do that is to have the borders and such be automatically re-sized such that it can work that way. I have no clue on how to do this, but for now here is this, should anyone else run into something like this.