# How do I Anchor Text and Shrink it to fit it on an Image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, image-manipulation

I fount this code off of the PIL API(here is the link: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/text-anchors.html) and I wanted to also shrink it depending on the size of the text while it is centered.

here is the anchoring code

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

font = ImageFont.truetype("mont.ttf", 48)
im = Image.new("RGB", (200, 200), "white")
d = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
d.text((100, 100), "Quick", fill="black", anchor="ms", font=font)
im.save('text.png')
```

And the outcome looks like this:

[image]

But if you increase the word size it looks like this:

[image]

So I just want the text to be centered and shrunk to fit the image

Comment: I think life might be easier with **wand**... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089810/2836621

Comment: yo I wanted to add this feature to a pillow thing I'm working on so I cant switch to something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No detail about the requirements, so here only for result image with fixed size (200, 200), so font size will be changed.

- Find the size of text by `ImageDraw.textsize`
- Draw on an image with same width as the text by `ImageDraw.text`
- Resize image to (200-2*border, 200-2*border) by `Image.resize`
- Paste the resized image to a 200x200 image by `Image.paste`

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def text_to_image(text, filename='text.png', border=20):
    im = Image.new("RGB", (1, 1), "white")
    font = ImageFont.truetype("calibri.ttf", 48)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    size = draw.textsize(text, font=font)
    width = max(size)
    im = Image.new("RGB", (width, width), "white")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.text((width//2, width//2), text, anchor='mm', fill="black", font=font)
    im = im.resize((200-2*border, 200-2*border), resample=Image.LANCZOS)
    new_im = Image.new("RGB", (200, 200), "white")
    new_im.paste(im, (border, border))
    new_im.show()
    # new_im.save(filename)

text_to_image("Hello World")
```

[image]