# How do i postion text to dynamically adjust itself according to its size in pillow python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

So i have a function that writes up some text in an image currently the text is fixed at a position but i want it to dynamically adjust itself based on size of text and lowest and right most coordinate i also wanna add the title after i add the body text here is my current code [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaoRv.png)

I also want the right most coordinate for the body text to be 302 and bottom most to be around 308 to 311. This is the output i expect when my gif finishes processing:

[image: my expected finished gif]
here the title and and body (in blue) adjust according to the size of text and stay between the specified left right most and bottom most coordinated while the top part varies.

Comment: Maybe condider using `wand`... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089810/2836621

Comment: post your code as minimal reproducible example as code block not as image