# Wrap text in the box

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to improve this code, so that it looks for the font size perfectly, for the quote given, and the author, and places it nicely in the middle of the image.
I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.
Maybe you know of a way to make it easier to place the text in the selected square on the image, using the largest font size possible, but no larger than the one set before.

```
SPACING = 20  # Add a new global variable to control the distance between the quote and the author's name
LEFT_RIGHT_PADDING = 20  # Add a new global variable to control the distance between the left and right edges
TOP_PADDING = 40  # Add a new global variable to control the distance between the top edge and the quote

def get_font_size(author, quote, font_path, author_font_path, min_font_size=42, max_font_size=96, image_width=1024,
                  image_height=1024):
    max_width = image_width - 2 * LEFT_RIGHT_PADDING
    max_height = image_height - 3 * TOP_PADDING

    optimal_font_size = min_font_size - 2
    min_overflow = float("inf")

    for font_size in range(min_font_size, max_font_size + 1):
        font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, font_size)
        print(f"Trying font size {font_size}...")
        wrapped_text, max_line_width, line_count = wrap_text(quote, max_width=max_width, max_height=max_height, font=font)

        line_height = font.getmask('A').getbbox()[3]
        total_height = line_count * (line_height + 10)

        author_font_size = int(font_size * 0.90)
        author_font = ImageFont.truetype(author_font_path, author_font_size)
        author_lines, max_author_width, author_line_count = wrap_text(author, max_width=max_width, max_height=140, font=author_font, single_line=True)

        overflow = max(0, max_line_width - max_width) + max(0, total_height - max_height)

        if overflow < min_overflow:
            min_overflow = overflow
            optimal_font_size = font_size

            if overflow == 0:
                break

    return optimal_font_size


def wrap_text(text, max_width, max_height, font, single_line=False):
    space_width = font.getmask('A').getbbox()[2]
    max_chars_per_line = max_width // space_width

    lines = textwrap.wrap(text, width=max_chars_per_line)
    line_height = font.getmask('A').getbbox()[3]
    total_height = len(lines) * line_height

    if total_height > max_height:
        lines = lines[:max_height // line_height]

    line_widths = [sum([font.getmask(char).getbbox()[2] for char in line if font.getmask(char)]) for line in lines]
    max_line_width = max(line_widths) if line_widths else 0

    if single_line:
        return [lines[0]], max_line_width, len(lines)

    return lines, max_line_width, len(lines)


def draw_multiline_text(draw, position, text_lines, font, fill):
    x, y = position
    for line in text_lines:
        mask = font.getmask(line)
        if mask:
            draw.text((x, y), line, font=font, fill=fill)
            y += mask.getbbox()[3] + 10


def create_quote_image(author, quote, font_path, author_font_path, font_size, img_name):
    img = Image.new('RGB', (1024, 1024), color='black')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, font_size)
    quote_lines, max_quote_width, quote_line_count = wrap_text(quote, max_width=1024 - 2 * LEFT_RIGHT_PADDING,
                                                               max_height=1024 - 3 * TOP_PADDING, font=font)
    quote_height = sum([(font.getmask(line).getbbox()[3] if font.getmask(line) else 0) + 10 for line in quote_lines]) - 10
    quote_x_position = (1024 - max_quote_width) // 2
    quote_y_position = (1024 - quote_height) // 2
    quote_position = (quote_x_position, quote_y_position)
    draw_multiline_text(draw, quote_position, quote_lines, font, fill='white')

    author_font_size = int(font_size * 0.85)
    author_font = ImageFont.truetype(author_font_path, author_font_size)
    author_lines, max_author_width, author_line_count = wrap_text(author, max_width=1024 - 2 * LEFT_RIGHT_PADDING,
                                                                  max_height=140, font=author_font, single_line=True)
    author_height = sum([(author_font.getmask(line).getbbox()[3] if author_font.getmask(line) else 0) + 10 for line in author_lines]) - 10
    author_x_position = (1024 - max_author_width) // 2
    author_y_position = quote_y_position + quote_height + SPACING
    author_position = (author_x_position, author_y_position)
    draw_multiline_text(draw, author_position, author_lines, author_font, fill='white')

    img.save(img_name, 'JPEG')
```

[image: This is example how working, for long quote.]

I am looking for a way to display a caption on a given square with a maximum font size, depending on the length of the caption, and line wrapping.
Surely there is a library that does this.
I would like to specify x,y in pixels where the start will be, and the width and height of the box where to paste, and the maximum font size.
Let's say the caption is short like "To be or not to be" and like the Jobs quote "Your work is going to fill a large part of your life, and the only way to be truly satisfied is to do what you believe is great work. And the only way to do great work is to love what you do. If you haven't found it yet, keep looking. Don't settle. As with all matters of the heart, you'll know when you find it.". For the first example, I would like a maximum font size of 96, and for the second example, I would like a maximum font size that still fills the filled box.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What image library are you using? Please [edit] and add the tag for it plus the imports in the code. Ideally, make a [mre]. For more tips, please read [ask].

Comment: I'd add image to the question iillustrating current state and mark the issues on it

Comment: Have read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089810/2836621