# How to properly implement word wrapping in Pillow/PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to automatically create a user profile using Pillow. I need a description field that 1.) automatically inserts line breaks to prevent X overflow and 2.) maximizes font size and shrinks it as necessary.

[Wand seems to have a native implementation of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089810/2836621) with its `Image.Caption()` method. I am trying to confine this project to Python libraries, however, and would prefer not to use ImageMagick.

[image: Large Font Size Word Wrap]
[image: Medium Font Size Word Wrap]
[image: Small Font Size Word Wrap]

As the images show, the font size progressively decreases as more text is added to fit in the confined white area.

Comment: Still don't know a sensible way with Pillow... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089810/2836621