Create image fitted to text in python
Is there a canonical way in python to create a new image that fits exactly a given text in python? With pillow or something similar?
Like I would for example do with ImageMagick:
convert -font Calibri -pointsize 24 label:"Sample text with a foo bar attached to it." sample.png
Do I have to create an image of which I know it is oversized, draw the text and then crop it to image content?

You could use Python subprocess command to call your Imagemagick command. Or you could use Python Wand, which uses Imagemagick to do the label: command.

See textbbox() https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html

And wand https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089810/2836621

The reason I do not directly use ImageMagick is, I am in a rather strict environment, where everything I end up using has to be validated.
My current solution:
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

img = Image.new("L", (200, 100))
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
d.text((3, 3), "My Text", fill=255)
image_box = img.getbbox()
result=img.crop(image_box)

And from that work on result.
